# Tomcat's context path for a webapp not working

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, artifactory

I'm installing Artifactory (http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) under a default tomcat installation (ubuntu server distribution). I create a /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml file with the following contents:

```
<Context path="/maven" docBase="${artifactory.home}/webapps/artifactory.war" debug="0">
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false"/>
</Context>
```

I want artifactory to be served under http://serverhostname:8080/maven , but it gets served under http://serverhostname:8080/artifactory instead. Any clues?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Context` docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) state that the base name of the file will be used so it's likely that the `path` attribute is simply ignored.

Comment: Yes, i've found this during the weekend... Thanks!

Comment: @kschneid: I found [bug#46713](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46713) referring the same problem. Any workaround for this? E.g. I would like to package `context.xml` to application and deploy the WAR to a certain application context path...