# How to remove the application name in URL? tomcat + httpd

Tags: java, tomcat, apache

everyone

I made a web application by Apache Click Framework, and just throwed it into tomcat behind httpd.

(assume my domain name is www.domain.com.)
So I can access my app by the URL: www.myDomain.com/myApp/pages/login.htm

My questions is, how to remove the "myApp" part in this url by configuration in httpd or tomcat? because my domain name already has some words like "myApp".

Comment: You need to do URL rewriting which most of framework supports like struts, spring mvc, that you can configure in your web.xml in case of java web app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0/51167549#51167549

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply name your war file `root.war` and deploy it to tomcat.
You probably have to remove the preconfigured `ROOT/` directory in tomcat first, if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, sounds quick but... dirty.

Comment: It is the standard way, as only one application can be root. No need to reconfigure Tomcat, works on any installation out of the box. Works also on Jetty, btw.

Comment: Got it, will try. but is this OK for httpd? I mean proxy to tomcat part: "proxypass / /usr/local/tomcat/root"

Comment: You mean `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8080/`, I guess? Works.

Comment: I have the same probelm and I have changed the war file name to root  but not sure how to remove the preconfigured Root/ directory

Comment: I had to rename to ROOT.war (using all caps). Using root.war did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do URL rewriting which most of framework supports like struts, spring mvc, that you can configure in your web.xml in case of java web app

Please Check if you can do with tomcat server.xml in below way ( But I am not sure with this, URL rewriting will solve your problem)

Refer: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html.

**etc/hosts** to add something like below

127.0.0.1 mydomain.com

**server.xml changes**

```
<Host name="bbstats.localhost" appBase="webapps/myapp"
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
      xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>


<Context path="/myapp" docBase="bbstats" debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"> 
</Context>
```

Comment: Good idea Pal, I usually just throw the .war file to the tomcat webapp directory and let it do the rest. I never tried to modify the tomcat config file cause I don't what that mean. I will check your way. and BTW, the URL rewriting must be supported by the framework for using it?