# URL issue while deploying war file in Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat7

When I deploy my app in dev environment it works fine. When I try to deploy it on production environment, Tomcat gives additional path parameter which cause problems in my app.

Example:
localhost:port/home.html -> localhost:port/AppName/home.html

Same goes to static resources eg. My Image is located at adress: localhost:port/static/index.jpg and on production env I need to put localhost:port/AppName/static/index.jpg

Is there any Spring configuration that helps to aovid that?
Do you know any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution without changing your server configuration.delete ROOT.war from your server and paste your war here rename it as ROOT.war.

Second solution is find your server.xml. add context here

```
 <Context path="/" docBase="your application name here" reloadable="true" />
```

don't forget path="/". And change if existing source has the path "/" to something else so it will not conflict.

Comment: Thank you. That is an option. I am going to try this. But is there any other possibility?

Comment: I Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems other people have already ask themselves the same question. These answers may help you (You just need to name you app as root.war):

[Detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325171/setting-default-application-in-tomcat-7)

[Short one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738546/how-to-remove-the-application-name-in-url-tomcat-httpd)