# how to add a web application to Tomcat 6 in linux

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I installed tomcat 6 and want to add my web app to launch the URL.
I followed [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

I created root.xml in /conf/Catalina/localhost/ path. And in root.xml file I have this

```
<Context path="/root" docBase="/scratch/rsarda/view_storage/web/appv2"/>
```

When I launch the url localhost:8080/root I got "HTTP Status 404" error. Also I don't see any error in /logs.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a "path" attribute in your `<Context>` element: Tomcat will use the name of the `.xml` file as the context path. Depending on other configuration, you may have to restart Tomcat in order to have it detect your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried without path attribute as well. But the behaviour was same. I even restarted Tomcat after the change.

Comment: What files and directories are in `/scratch/rsarda/view_storage/web/appv2`? Is that path read/execute for the Tomcat user?

Comment: You didn't answer both questions:L what is in `/scratch/rsarda/view_storage/web/appv2`?