# Deployment in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7

Here is the contents of my sample.xml (in the conf/Catalina/localhost/):

`<Context path="/sample" reloadable="true" docBase="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.14\test"/>`

And I put the sample.war file under this directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.14\test. But tomcat did not deploy the war file.

I saw the following message in the tomcat console

"INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor sample.xml from D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.14 \conf\Catalina\localhost "

unpackWars is true.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if the answer given by Frank Paaske at [HOWTO set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0][1] can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0