# Deploy war file in tomcat using Linux

Tags: linux, gwt, tomcat6

I am using **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)** and **apache-tomcat-6.0.35**.tomcat install on port 8080 than i change in 80(default) . Using tomcat deploy war file(abc.war) successfully but i want to access this application as (`www.abc.com`). plz suggest how to replace index file(ROOT)??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: yes u r right..i have also a domain but my problem is differ after deploy war file i run application like(ip:80/abc) so i want to change this in www.abc.com.

Comment: Do you have a local DNS server? If yes is your machine configured to lookup to your local server? Please give more details in the question

Comment: and what error do you get on typing abc.com

Comment: @MayankSharma i have a public ip like(http://74.125.224.72/) ar but my question is this after deploy war file i have to access this ip (www.abc.com) abc is deploy war file. now i am to access like ip:abc

Comment: i just ask how to remove/change index file from tomcat(Root folder) ar any other suggestion..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: You may do it with eclipse. It has remote deployment features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the project name from domain on cPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728330/how-to-remove-the-project-name-from-domain-on-cpanel)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to pay for a domain name and point it at your IP address.
2. Create (or symlink) your application's .xml file to ROOT.xml in the webapps directory. This will mean you can access the application using '/' as well as '/abc'.

Comment: this doesn't provide the answer, it doesn't allow mapping to the specified url.

Comment: What do you mean? The DNS entry will set the hostname, and using 'ROOT.xml' will remove the /abc part

Comment: How do you want using ROOT.xml in the webapps directory to remove the /abc part? And it doesn't remove as well.

Comment: ROOT.xml is a special app name, which is the default for that Tomcat instance and will be loaded when browsing to the root of the tomcat server: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html (search for ROOT.xml)