# How to remove the project name from domain on cPanel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2, cpanel

I have uploaded my war files on cPanel and it perfectly works but how can I remove the project name from the address,

It should be

```
  www.example.com/index.html
```

but it is

```
  www.example.com/MyProject/index.html   << it includes the project name
```

based on this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738546/how-to-remove-the-application-name-in-url-tomcat-httpd) I have changed the name of my war file to root but it still does not work, although I do not know how to remove the pre-configured `ROOT/` directory