# How to take out the project name from domain?

Tags: spring, struts2, tomcat7, cpanel, whm

**(Firstly it is not a duplicate, as the other question is not visible to users any more, and none of the answers are correct)** I need to remove the project name of my Java application from the domain, but could not find an efficient way yet.

Currently it is

```
www.example.com/MyProject/index.jsp
```

but it should be as following (without project name)

```
www.example.com/index.jsp
```

the following question is similar to my question but still no-one has answered correctly, and since it 's been posted a long time ago I reckon it wont be visible to be answered by more people.

> [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728330/how-to-remove-the-project-name-from-domain-on-cpanel)

The following question also shows how to remove it in eclipse but not when the website is live

[URL issue with tomcat include project name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160241/url-issue-with-tomcat-include-project-name)

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to do this... It is particular to the application server. What you are deploying are applications so by default the application name seems reasonable. You can tell the application server to use a different name or no name at all. Once again this configuration depends on the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I should have answered this question and think maybe it should have been a comment with a recommendation to move the question to a server stack exchange group...

Comment: thanks, but do not know how to configure application server to remove the project name, how can I move it to server stack exchange group?

Comment: flag -> needs moderator attention, wrote "move to server fault" is what I did... sometimes you can say: flag ->  it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate -> and select the proper site but the site was not listed.