# Tomcat removing context path from URL

Tags: java, tomcat7

I can only access my application when I give context path like:

```
www.mydomain.com/projName
```

and not with:

```
www.mydomain.com
```

If I give `www.mydomain.com`, it loads tomcat application under ROOT. What change do I have to make to be able to access application without context path?

Comment: change the folder name to your project name.

Comment: [HOWTO set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: @:SuKu  - I dont want context path in the URL when user first launches the application. URL should be simply "www.mydomain.com"

Answer (score 4):

You can change the below in your `{CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml` to point to your webapp,

```
    <Context path="" docBase="your application folder relative 
               path from webapps" debug="0"> 
    </Context>
```

Comment: Example : <Context path="" docBase="Folder name of app in {CATALINA_HOME}/webapps folder" debug="0" privileged="true" />

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the contents of your configuration files, specially your context.xml located in /META-INF/context.xml.

In that file, did you try to specify the context path to ""?

Something like:

`<Context path=""/>`

Don't forget to redeploy your solution after any change to context.xml.