# apache-tomcat 7.0 does not unpack .war?

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to deploy my app to the server, and then I can visit the app like this:

```
http://10.10.10.10/index.jsp
```

but not

```
http://10.10.10.10/bar/index.jsp
```

so this is my host configuration in server.xml:

```
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context docBase="/home/foo/bar.war" reloadable="false" path=""/>
   </Host>
```

But, after I start up tomcat

> sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

I found that tomcat does not unpack the war file in $CATALINA_HOME/webapps.
then I try to delete all files in $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT, but it does not matter.
so is there someone come cross this issue before? and how to solve the probelm?

Comment: Maybe you should set unpackWARs to true.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: @JoachimRohde I have try that, the problem exists too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tomcat 7 does not unpack WAR files from outside the Host's appBase into the appBase.

Tomcat 7 will run your application from the WAR.

Comment: By design. Unpacking WARs from outside the appBase opens up all sorts of tricky edge cases. No committer has felt the urge to scratch that particular itch so the restriction remains.

Comment: But will tomcat unpack it anywhere? tmp perhaps?

Comment: No. When I say "Tomcat does not unpack the WAR" that is exactly what I mean.