# I would like http://localhost:8080/ to have the same effect as accessing http://localhost:8080/basicSetup/index.xhtml

Tags: jsf, tomcat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>basic setup</display-name>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.faces</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

It should be accessed from domain like www.example.com without showing www.example.com/basicsetup.

Comment: try using `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Why didn't you check 'How to deploy a web application' section of your server in the first place and instead decided to ask here? Did you try to search at the very least? What is your server? If you search 'Your-server-name web application deployment', well, you'll most probably find the answer in the first link.

Comment: @skuntsel, a bit harsh there, mate

Comment: @kolossus I didn't intend to be. Rather, it was more of a *'there-is-definitely-a-good-answer-in-the-official-documentation-that'll-turn-up-on-the-first-google-link'* flavour!

Comment: What is the server you deploy to?

Comment: server is tomcat 7 server

Comment: Ah, @skuntsel, I see :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be wise to go through [Tomcat 7 server documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) on the issue, especially the following part, recited below for you (emphasis mine:

> The Context element represents a web application, which is run within a particular virtual host. Each web application is based on a Web Application Archive (WAR) file ...
>
> The web application used to process each HTTP request is selected by Catalina based on matching the longest possible prefix of the Request URI against the context path of each defined Context.
>
> You may define as many Context elements as you wish. Each such Context MUST have a unique context name within a virtual host. The context path does not need to be unique (see parallel deployment below). In addition, **a Context must be present with a context path equal to a zero-length string. This Context becomes the default web application for this virtual host**, and is used to process all requests that do not match any other Context's context path.

So, to sum it up: you need to have `<Context path="" ... />` defined as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

You can find the needed details in the answer to [HOWTO set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706950/1820286) question.