# servlet context to tomcat 7 root

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Whats the best approach to place servlet context to `tomcat 7` root? I have tried [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0) but didn't work for me; i'm using `Apache Tomcat/7.0.42`.

P.S: I don't want to rename the project name as `ROOT.war`.

### Update

I have placed the `context` tag as explained in one of the answers, but still getting the `tomcat` home page as root:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"               
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
         prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />    
   <Context docBase="app-renderer" path="/" reloadable="true" />
 </Host>
```

### Update 2

the problem was about the `ROOT` directory in `webapps`, after removing now I could have the app as root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Tomcat's `conf/server.xml` file, you'll typically have an entry

```
<Context docBase="yourApp" path="/somePath" reloadable="true" source="someSource"/>
```

for your application.

Change the path to `/`

```
<Context docBase="yourApp" path="/" reloadable="true" source="someSource"/>
```

Add this in the `Host` entry. For example

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
<Context docBase="yourApp" path="/" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

where the `docBase` attribute is the name of your app as it appears in the `webapps` folder. [The docs explain the meaning of each attribute.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)

Comment: there is no `<context..` tag in the servlet.xml but I have add this but its not working.

Comment: @stsd Try starting Tomcat with your jar in the webapps folder. It should create an entry for it. Then stop Tomcat and change it.

Comment: It's not an entry that preexists, it's one that you have to define. To tell Tomcat, or else it will go by default. @stsd

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I did, there is no such an entry, if I addd its not working, btw what is `source="someSource`?

Comment: @stsd Forget about `source`. It's an Eclipse attribute. Give me a second.

Comment: @stsd You can add the `<Context>` element yourself inside the `<Host>` element. You must not have a `ROOT` app. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I did, its not working.. root is still pointing at tomcat home.

Comment: @stsd Can you update your question with some details (`server.xml`, name of app, etc.)? It is working for me.

Comment: @stsd If your application folder in webapps is named `app-renderer` and you have no `ROOT` application in webapps, what you've posted should work. What is your servlet url-mapped to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: tnx worked.. I update the post what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check the [context documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context). You're looking for the `docBase` attribute for your webapp's path and the `path` attribute for the root context, e.g. leave it empty as described in the attribute's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the `.war` file to `ROOT` follow below steps:

`1.` Create a file named `ROOT.xml` under the `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/`

`2.` paste below code into the `ROOT.xml` file:

```
<Context
  docBase="/home/user/YOUR_PROJECT/target/YOUR_PROJECT.war"
  path=""
  reloadable="true"
/>
```

Now you can access your project in tomcat root.

To have a clean project remove `tomcat/webapps/ROOT` directory.