# Spring mvc application does not work as war in tomcat but it works well from IDE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, apache-tiles

please help me to figure out this strange behavior, I have a project based on Spring here https://github.com/riuvshin/spring-mvc-learn and I want deploy *.war to tomcat 7.0. When I deploy that war to clean tomcat according to logs it's should work every thing is ok, but when I try to open localhost:8080/contacts I've got 404 error...

If I launch that application from my IDE (intellij) it works fine, I will be super happy if any one can explain me what I missed.

Comment: Post the relevant areas of the `catalina.out` log file.

Comment: here is my output: http://freetexthost.com/oq0xlzi3f5

Comment: I dont think those logs contain a trace of when you got the 404. Can you upload that? Also what are you using to build a WAR? Maven if so it looks like your not including the required config files in the war, which could be on your classpath in your ide

Comment: there is no any traces on console, 404 I've got in browser when trying to open application url.
I am using maven (mvn clean install) then get war file from /temp folder and put it in to tomcat/webapps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `catalina.out` log clearly shows that your `@Controller` is mapped to the path `/contacts`

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/contacts],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.apress.prospring3.ch17.web.controller.ContactController.list(org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

However you are trying to access this handler with the path

```
localhost:8080/contacts
```

This will only work if you webapp is configured to have a context path of `/` and I'm pretty sure it isn't.

Try using

```
localhost:8080/[myapp]/contacts
```

where `[myapp]` is the name of your application's folder in the `webapps` folder.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534436/servlet-context-to-tomcat-7-root/18534628#18534628) on how to change that path.

Comment: YES! Thank you a lot! that's it! in my IDE context path configured to `/`, you save my brain! (bow)