# Deploying dynamic web project to production server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I've got a project called CodeProjects that I've made in eclipse and want to upload it to my remote server, the problem is I need to configure it run in the ROOT folder so I can access the site via domain.com/ but tomcat unpacks the .war file and configures it to run as domain.com/CodeProjects/ how do I change this? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried it personally but this should work for you

[Set context path to web root][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: I set context root within eclipse from "CodeProjects" to "/" and it still doesnt work

Comment: Btw how do I set context path to web root?