# how to delete the application context of my web?

Tags: web-services, jsf, tomcat

I've a web (jsf) running in tomcat on EC2 server amazon and my domain www.mydomain.tk and I'd like to show my web when I type my domain. At the moment I've to type  www.mydomain.tk/ContexOfMyApp .

www.mydomain.tk/ContexOfMyApp (at the moment ) --> www.mydomain.tk

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

SOL: [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tomcat `webapps` directory try to rename your application as `ROOT`. `ContextOfMyApp` will become `ROOT`

Comment: Your solution is ok but only it's valid for one app by tomcat