# how to remove the port number/name of the App in a hosting machine

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I was trying to deploy a war file on Tomcat on a production Server and i am facing some problems. I can access my site using  www.mydomain.com:8080/myappname   but what I really want is to access my app by just using www.mydomain.com.   I would really appreciate any kind of help as I'm really stuck on how to solve this issue. Note: I am using tomcat as a web server Thanks very much! Anteneh

Comment: You may want to front tomcat with apache or nginx, since tomcat isn't really very good as a general web server (for example serving static files)

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson , but i think it is too late for me to change the server. could you please suggest an alternative solution? Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/293348/configure-nginx-for-jboss-tomcat) is some info on how to use nginx for static files and forward servlet requests to tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Tomcat's default port to 80. See instructions at http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

In addition, you need to change the context path of your application. You can find the instructions on this thread [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: The problem with running it on port 80 (using this method) is that it'd have to run as root/administrator, which security wise isn't a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks @user3594557 , another problem with port 80 is that another process is using it and i can't change it. And if it can help the machine is running on Windows Server 2008 r2. thanks

Comment: @Anteneh If something else is running on port 80, you'll need to make that process forward the requests. The only other way to access the site without using a port number is to either 1) run the process on port 80 2) Map accesses to port 80 to actual port 8080 in your firewall.

Comment: By another process, I meant Plesk is using port 80

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , the problem i have it that , I don't have control over the firewall of the server, I am using a hosting company. what do you suggest?