# How to test a REST WS using URL

Tags: java, web-services, rest, url

I've Googled how to but I can't seem to find a step-by-step guide for a beginner. I just want to make sure a class is working and printing fine. A lot of tutorials said to just put the URL in the browser but I don't even know how to get the URL of my web service.

What I've done so far:
1. Created a WAR file out of the project
2. Deployed the WAR file on Tomcat

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0zPgiE-X2M) video on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the path will be based on the name of your WAR file, but can be easily configured.

see this response:  [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)