# REST Servlet is working in development but on remote Tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat, remote-server

Hello I am new to Tomcat development and have a question.

When I am trying to develop a REST Servlet it works under development with netbeans and tomcat 8, but when I try to create a .war file and load it to a remote tomcat via webinterface, it doesn't work.

So I just created a new Web Application in Netbeans and changed it a little bit:

```
@Path("test1")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;


    public GenericResource() {
    }


    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml() {

       return "<xml rest='cool'></xml>";
    }

}
```

and

```
    package test;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("test")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(test.GenericResource.class);
    }

}
```

So when I deploy it in Netbeans it works perfectly to use

```
http://localhost:8080/ServerTest/test/test1
```

But when I create a war and develop it to remote tomcat - it only shows error 404 when I use "http://xyz.at/ServerTest/test/test1"

But why? I heard this shouldn't happen when I use servlet 3.0.

**EDIT:**
The index.html worked before - only the rest services (GET, POST) don't work yet.

It's funny because in netbeans it works perfectly.

I just noticed that in development I have tomcat 8.0.9 but on remote server I have 8.0.15 - does this make trouble?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue. did you manage it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly anymore because it was a long time ago.
I think the solution was to explicit start the servlet-application in tomcat web manager. It was not activated per default.
Did you solve your problem? If yes, how did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are putting it not to the root path.

As quick solution try to rename your war to **ROOT.war** and then deploy it.

You can read more about context path configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the index.html worked before - only the rest services (GET, POST) doesn't work yet It's funny because in netbeans in works perfect. I just noticed that in development I have tomcat 8.0.9 but on remote server i have 8.0.15 - does this make trouble?

Comment: I am having same issue, have you found a solution?