# direct tomcat webapp url

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have a webapp I am trying to deploy to AWS in a tomcat setup. It's a single paged application that runs from an index.html page located something like this:

```
http://example.com/resources/index.html
```

How do I make it so when someone accesses my server at `example.com` they get redirected to https and all they see in the address bar is `example.com` rather than the `.../resources/index.html`?

Comment: This question should go to https://serverfault.com

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey What web framework are you using?

Comment: I am using spring, with an angularjs front end.

Comment: are you deploying as resources.war?

Comment: I think this is what you need:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: I dont think this is quite what I'm looking for. This talks about how to get rid of the leading context, but not the path to the index file. This is basically telling my how to go from `example.com/example/resources/index.html` to `example.com/resources/index.html`. I am trying to end up with `example.com` where that points to `/resources/index`.