# Deploy multiple WARs on Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, war

How to make it possible to deploy deploy multiple WARs on Tomcat one of which is ROOT and how to passed the requests to corresponding application.

like:
`/ - main app`
`/appA - app A`
`/appB - app B`

How to make the main app skip urls `/appA` and `/appB` ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have ROOT access on the server you are running tomcat on?

Comment: yes, but ROOT I meant like ROOT.war which is the default on tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html), your second question "How to make the main app skip urls /appA and /appB ?" will be solved automatically:

> The web application used to process each HTTP request is selected by Catalina based on matching the longest possible prefix of the Request URI against the context path of each defined Context.

The first question is discussed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0). You can apply one of the solutions listed there according your Tomcat Version, environmet, etc.