# 403 access denied on changing name of ROOT [Tomcat]

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Seeking inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0) , I changed my web context folder name from say `MyApp` to `ROOT` and `ROOT` to `ROOT-BAK` but before changing MyApp to ROOT i made a index.html file in `MyApp`.

It didn't work. so i changed everything again to the way it initially was.
`ROOT` -> `MyApp` and `ROOT-BAK` --> `ROOT`

Now i have two completely disjoint questions -

1. I am working on AWS EC2 ( which is nothing but a computer running somewhere). There is a loadbalancer on top of it. When i changed the `MyApp` to `ROOT` inspite of having index.html my instance went out of service from ELB. Why did that happen ?
2. After making everything as before when i hit my url, it gives me access denied. Why is it happening ?

i basically made two changes - one is create index.html in MyApp  and other is renaming of folders.

Comment: i didn't make any changes anywhere ( please read the update question) except renaming the folders @javahippie

Answer (score 1):

**For question 1** - Check at the Load Balancer if there is mapping of URL pattern. Most of the time with load balancer's we specify specific pattern only to be accessed from consumer end considering the security factors.
For instance, if you are using Apache or OHS you could check the entries for  tag having a specific pattern such as /MyApp mapped to multiple node ips/hostanmes. You can change that to /ROOT and everything should work the way you expected.

**For question 2** - It brings a different element here as if you have reverted everything as it was earlier and have also restarted the servers (all the nodes in cluster) it should work as earlier. Only exception being you might need to clear/delete the contents of **work** folder under TOMCAT_HOME directory for new web context to be reloaded, sometimes this creates problem.