# reflect on web-application changes in servlets class file

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I just want   to know  how to make automatic reflect on web application  if i make changes  in my servlets class file .
Because when ever I make changes in servlets class file I have to do server shutdown and startup 
Otherwise go to tomcat web application manager 
And reload the web-application 
Is there another method which automatic do this

Answer (score 1):

Set `<Context reloadable="true" />`, Catalina to monitor classes in `/WEB-INF/classes/` and `/WEB-INF/lib` for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development. But not in production environment. See the [reloadable doc.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)

**Edit:**

[How to set context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: Satya I can't understand where should i  make changes reloadable="true".and I'm using tomcat 6.0.44

Comment: After making ROOT.xml place in localhost directory its not working why ? I'm using tomcat 7.0.63

Answer (score -1):

Edit install_dir/conf/server.xml and add a DefaultContext subelement to the main Service element and supply true for the reload able attribute
Add

```
 <DefaultContext reloadable="true"/>
```

before the

```
</host>
```

tag.

Comment: Where should I write this tag . I'm new in servlets programming

Comment: @Sajid Dayer I hope this could help you