# define application context for root aplication

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I have static context defined in `server.xml`

```
<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="my-module"/>
```

I need to specify context for this application. I tried to add `my-module.xml` and also `ROOT.xml` to `conf/Catalina/localhost` but that didn't solved my issue.

I'm still getting error

> Unexpected exception: Name [jdbc/my-module] is not bound in this
>   Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

my context.xml

```
<Context>    
<Resource 
        name="jdbc/my-module" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        username="AFE" 
        password="AFE" 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-server:1537:DB" 
        defaultAutoCommit="false" />
</Context>
```

How can I then specify context for root application?

Comment: This post has the correct configuration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: it should be `java:/comp/env/jdbc/my-module`

Comment: @JohnKuhns that looks promising however not working for me. I have static context in server.xml ```<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/apache-tomcat/my-module/my-module"/>``` and also that same in ROOT.xml in conf/Catalina/localhost but have still same problem :(

Comment: @JohnKuhns OK I resolved that. Link you posted is ok, when you don't specify Context in server.xml. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually you mustn't manually edit server.xml. After serever pool execution it must add it automatically. Context.xml must be in META-INF folder.Server tomcat.

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/DATABASE"
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="test" password="test" 
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
        defaultAutoCommit="false"
        defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
        connectionProperties="useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;"
        url="jdbc:derby://localhost/DataBase"/>
</Context>
```

and here connection code

```
private static DBConnector instance;

public static synchronized DBConnector getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DBConnector();
    }
    return instance;
}

private DBConnector(){
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        // DATABASE - the name of data source
        ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DATABASE");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

private DataSource ds;
```

Comment: I know about how this works for any application. But I'm asking about default application. Lets say that I have myapp.war which is statically defined in server.xml as root <Context path="/" docBase="myapp" />. But when I create myapp.xml context config, jdbc is not picked up.

Comment: Try to follow my steps 1)in eclipse create war file. 2) put it into your tomcat directory. 3) run tomcat server. 4) shutdown it and in webapps folder rename your project name to ROOT. 5) in tomcat/conf/context.xml add resource as mentioned above.6) start tomcat ... Must work

Comment: Yes this way it will work. But I don't want to have global resource as you wrote (tomcat/conf/context.xml). I just want to have appliation resources conf/Catalina/localhost/appname.xml and this will be my default webapp.

Comment: there exists folder with name work and it contains your app name folder, you must put context there, but it don't contain ROOT.