# Getting Tapestry to respond on root URL

Tags: maven, jetty, tapestry

I've gone through [Tapestry's documentation](https://tapestry.apache.org/documentation.html) and am unable to figure out this one.

Tapestry sets up URLs as `myurl/myappname?message=hello`.
However, I want to serve requests as `myurl?message=hello`.

My client expects to pass parameters on the root URL.

How do I configure Tapestry to do so?
I don't want my Web Application name to be visible in the URL.

I can see Tapestry intercept requests on `myurl`, but it responds with `Error 404`.

Please help and thanks in advance! I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function of your servlet container, not Tapestry. For Tomcat, see this question: [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: I don't think @karthik-b is asking about context path, but rather how to setup a `url-pattern` to match his use case.

Comment: It was a function of Jetty indeed. I had to add:<contextPath>/</contextPath> to pom.xml and it works fine now!