# Tomcat running two web modules under same port

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am newbie to web application. I already have web application running in tomcat7. I want to run other web app on same port but probably different URLs.
For eg.

http://localhost:8080/  --> goes to app1 by default
http://localhost:8080/app2

How can I do that in tomcat7?

Comment: Just deploy both applications in Tomcat and you should be good to go.

Comment: That's exactly what Tomcat already does.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your app1's war as ROOT.war and app2's war as app2.war, Tomcat will deploy theese exactly where you want.
You can also configure it in the server.xml file.

Check out this post for details: [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: Please don't recommend using `server.xml` to set the context path for a web application.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz thanks for your warning. 
In documentation, alternative ways are explained for configuring the context.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Comment: Thanks @okan That helped.

Answer (score 0):

As other respondents have noted ROOT.war will serve up on / now if you want hi have / on one Fully qualified domain name and app2 on a different you have to configure more than one host elements in server.XML each accessing a different directory for webapps