# tomcat7 fronted by apache 2.4 with ajp - removing tomcat context

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, proxy

I'm trying since days to remove the tomcat context from the URL. The tomcat URL is http://diovmcos03.diogenes.ch:8081/diogenes/leser.html and my httpd virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www2.diogenes.ch
        ErrorLog logs/ajp.error.log
        CustomLog logs/ajp.log combined
        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset Off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8010/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8010/
</VirtualHost>
```

when I enter www2.diogenes.ch it shows the URL http://www2.diogenes.ch/diogenes/leser.html but I would like to have it like this: diogenes.ch/leser.html (without "diogenes"). 
The problem is, that I can't proxy / to ajp://localhost:8010/diogenes because my DAM and some other virtual folders are not located behind /diogenes/. So if I redirect every request from / to /diogenes/ all my pictures and css and stuff won't be reachable.

I tried best to combine the proxy with mod_rewrite, but I couldn't find any solution yet. Your help would be highly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can rename `diogenes.war` to `ROOT.war`. This will take you directly to your application's home page. If you do not wish to rename the war file, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: thank you very much! The problem is, that the application name is "magnoliaPublic", so the full URL is www2.diogenes.ch/magnoliaPublic/diogenes/leser.html. the .war is already unvisible in the URL... Thanks again