# Map web application url to a domain name including port number

Tags: linux, tomcat, dns

I have a web application deployed on tomcat with the following url:

175.68.115.4:443/timesheet

The ip address has been mapped to a domain www.mytime.com So now the application is accessible on the following url: www.mytime.org:443/timesheet

I want my application to be accessible from this url only : www.mytime.com 
The port number and the context name should be mapped together on the url. How can I do this? Any tutorial available on this?

Glad if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change to port 80 for http and 443 for https. Edit your server.xml file and change `<Connector port="8080"` to `<Connector port="80"`. If you are using https search similarly for `8443` and change it to `443`

Deploy your app with the name ROOT.war and your domain should take you to the home page of timesheet website. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0) if you do not want to rename your war file

Comment: Yes it should be 443. So it's not necessary for me to change port to 80 since it need to be https

Comment: Yes. Also i would highly recommend using Apache as a front end to your tomcat application. Basically, Apache would be your interface to the web and it will forward requests to your Tomcat container. It allows for better and more easier controls over setting up URLs, redirects, SSL certificates, monitoring,etc.

Comment: Currently i have this in my server.xml

<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<!-- <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />-->

Normally i use the first one with 8090. As you can see the 8443 is commented in tomcat. What should I do? Comment the first one, and change the port 8443 to 443?