# How to change application's url path in tomcat 8 to ROOT path?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, catalina

I tried to change the application's path by adding next line to "conf/server.xml":

```
 <Context path="" docBase="myapp.war" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

Then I restarted tomcat but nothing have changed. I have to use "localhost:8080/myapp/" to use my app. Is it possible to use "localhost:8080/" and that's all?

Comment: Did you try `<Context path="/" docBase="myapp.war" debug="0" reloadable="true" />`? Otherwise I think you want to deploy ROOT.war instead of myapp.war.

Comment: Yes. I tried: "", "/", "/foobar". Nothing works. Tomcat doesn't react on that changes at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: Yes. If I change the name of war to "ROOT.war" it works. But I don't understand why I can't change a path name in conf/server.xml

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!