# How to Set Context root in Spring Mvc Project

Tags: spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am Using Spring MVC project in Tomcat Server.Each time I run the application the server context root is changed.
How to set fixed context root?

My projectname is: DemoApplication,
first this context root is deployed the path is,
http://localhost:8080/DemoApplication

second time it is,
http://localhost:8080/Controller
Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydp" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
             <beans:value>com.Aquatech.Model.Area</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean> 
<beans:bean id="GenericDao" class="com.Aquatech.Dao.Impl.GenericDaoImpl">
 <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="GenericserviceDao" class="com.Aquatech.ServiceDao.Impl.GenericServiceDaoImpl">
 <beans:property name="genericDao" ref="GenericDao"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor"      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.Aquatech.Controller" />
```

Comment: please provide your web.xml, application context xml from Spring MVC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HOWTO set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: @vila your web.xml seems to fine. Also for tomcat the default context root is war name.

Answer (score 6):

> My projectname is: DemoApplication, first this context root is
>   deployed the path is, http://localhost:8080/DemoApplication and second
>   time it is, http://localhost:8080/Controller ?

**You NEED TO fix the root context** **for your web application** (DemoApplication) to fix the URL, which you can achieve with one of the below options:

(1) Set the `root context` as `DemoApplication` in Tomcat as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

(2) If you are using Maven, you can fix your war name by adding the below tag into the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>DemoApplication</finalName>
</build>
```

Once you are done with either of the above options, you should be able to access your application **controller** always with below url :

http://localhost:8080/DemoApplication/Controller

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IntelliJ IDE, u can go to top-right server (edit-configuration>select server (example:- tomcat 8.5.61)>Deployment).
There is a field "Application context: /(base url server_name)", here you can put whatever you want to keep.