# Why REST controller returns 404 status code?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to update data in my database. I am using jQuery/AJAX on frontend and REST/MyBatis/MySQL on backend. Unfortunately REST controller returns 404 status code. Please look at my REST controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/documents")
public class DocumentResources {

    private DocumentsMapper mapper;

    public DocumentResources(DocumentsMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @PostMapping("/updateDocument")
    public List<Documents> updateDocument (@RequestBody Documents document) {
        mapper.updateDocument(document);
        return mapper.getAllDocuments();
    }
}
```

Here is my DocumentsMapper class code:

```
@Mapper
public interface DocumentsMapper {
    @Select("select * from documents")
    List<Documents> getAllDocuments();

    @Update("UPDATE documents SET title = #{title}, author = #{author}, src = #{src} WHERE id =#{id}")
    void updateDocument(Documents document);
}
```

And here is my AJAX method:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();

var formData = {
    id : $("#target #id").val(),    
    title : $("#target #title").val(),
    author :  $("#target #author").val(),
    src: $("#target #src").val(),
    createTime : $("#target #createTime").val(),
    editTime : $("#target #editTime").val()
}

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8088/documents/updateDocument',
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {
        },
          error: function() {
                window.location = "/error";
                console.log('error', arguments);
              },
                complete: function() {
                console.log('complete', arguments);
              }
            }).done(function() {
              window.location = "/documents";
              console.log('done', arguments);
            });
  });
```

### Update

I've just tried to switch off Spring Security and POST method became accessible. Here is the authorization features:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/administrator/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/documents/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
        .and()
            .formLogin()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
//          .and()
//              .csrf()
                ;
}
```

### Update

I try to switch on SpringSecurity but disable CSRF `.csrf().disable()`. After that POST methods work. I think that disabling the CSRF is not a good idea. This may lead to XSS attacks. So I should configure CSRF-token generation and its interchange.

Comment: have you tried hitting your rest api via postman? What's the output then?

Comment: @Rinat can you check the logs, whether it shown "no mapping found for this url" ,  also please check after setting context path and try hitting with the new url,
this link myt be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670654/how-to-set-context-root-in-spring-mvc-project

Comment: @tryingtolearn output is: {"timestamp":"2018-10-17T07:08:26.074+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/documents/updateDocuments"}

Comment: It means there is a context path set in your application which needs to be appended in each request. Are you using springboot? If yes , check for context path property in application.properties

Comment: @tryingtolearn only server.port and spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.password, spring.datasource.username in my application.properties file. GET REST endpoints work, but POST not (((

Comment: @tryingtolearn yes, I'm using SpringBoot

Comment: The GET rest api that works is in same controller? Try adding a test GET api to this controller and see if it works?

Comment: @tryingtolearn, yes both GET and POST in the same controller (in same file)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) Please check spring startup logs : you can get the url initialized
> >     for the project
>
> 2) try putting context path for the application,
>
> > these link myt be helpful : 
> >           in spring MVC : [How to Set Context root in Spring Mvc Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670654/how-to-set-context-root-in-spring-mvc-project)
> >           in spring boot : [Add context path to Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application)
> >
> > sample url :
>
> http://localhost:8088/{contextPath}/documents/updateDocument
>
> > 3) better use API documentation like swagger ui, you can try hitting
> >     the url easly and get the available urls in your controller classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing @Autowired annotation in your code.
Try adding this annotation before Constructor and try again.
@Autowired
public DocumentResources(DocumentsMapper mapper){this.mapper = mapper;}

Comment: the context would have failed if OP'd had problems with injection.

Answer (score 0):

you need add projectName to addres
eg : http://localhost:8088/projectName/documents/updateDocument