# css files are not loading

Tags: jsp

I have developed a dynamic web project in Eclipse. Now I can access it through my browser using the following URL:

http://localhost:8080/MyDynamicWebApp/index/

If if remove '/' at the end i dont know why but my css files are not getting loaded.

Comment: Can you make the question little bit more clear ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyDynamicWebApp/ this is the url. I dont want '/' at the end.I dont know why but if i remove '/' when i run it my css files are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may rename eclipse project name.

Changing contex root is specific to the container in use

For example tomcat:
[How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

For example jboss:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, URLs that pointed to files did not include the trailing slash, while URLs that pointed to directories did include the trailing slash.
This means that:

http://website.com/example/ is a directory, while
http://website.com/example is a file.

This distinction speeds up page loading because the trailing slash immediately tells the web server to go to that example directory and look for the index.html or other default file.

When you go to a URL without the trailing slash, the web server looks for a file with that name. If it doesn’t find a file with that name, then it looks for a directory and looks for the default file in that directory.