# Issue in deploying application into tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have create a Spring Boot application successfully and when i execute the application via eclipse run as-> Spring Boot Application the application start successfully and i am able to access the home page via http://local host:8080/

But i start the tomcat independently and deploy the war file using tomcat app manager i am not able to access my application by http://local host:8080/ as this will open the tomcat home page not my applications.
Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should work:

1. Navigate to **TOMCAT_HOME/webapps** directory.
2. Rename the **ROOT** directory.
3. Create an empty directory **ROOT** inside  **TOMCAT_HOME/webapps**
4. Copy the contents of your **WAR** file to **TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT** directory
5. Restart tomcat and see if http://localhost:8080 works.

However, the right approach would be to create a specific context path for your web application and set is as **docBase** in your **server.xml**. Please refer [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0) for more information.

Comment: So Spring Boot app deploy into the tomcat into the same way?

Comment: I have provided the packaging type as war. As you suggested I have followed the process to change the root directory. Now i am able to access my application using localhost:8080. But strangly the default index page gets displayed not the one which i have configured. Do you required the directory structure or any specific file to understand this issue?

Comment: The problem here is: 1. When i run my application as run as -> spring boot application, it executed successfully  and i am able access my home page using localhost:8080. But When i execute it as run as -> Run on server i am not able to access it via localhost:8080. This is happening exactly when i am deploying the war into tomcat and try to access it using locathost:8080

Comment: No for development i am using Spring Tool Suit but i am deploying the generated war into different machine with external tomcat

Comment: Let me explain:  When i run my application on Spring Tool Suit by clicking Run as -> spring boot application option and once application started successfully and access the URL as localhost:8080, i am able to see my home page. But When i execute within STS but with another option as Run as -> Run on server the home page doesnot get appears by access localhost:8080 so this happening when i create a war file from STS and deploy it into external tomcat

Comment: No exceptions occure

Comment: i checked it, content is not added into war file

Comment: @AshishChauhan In that case, there's a problem with your war file creation. Please refer http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging, create war file correctly and then deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Please noticed two things:

1 update the deploy type as "war" in pom.xml

2 don't set server.port in  application.properties

3 ensure tomcat jar is provided in pom.xml

Please follow this link: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

In the application.properties file mention below,

```
server.port = 8080
server.contextPath=/myapp
```

Deploy myapp.war into server and Hit url in browser:

http://localhost:8080/myapp

**Note**: if you are using jar run then use below,

java -jar myapp.jar or From Eclispe you can do run as --> Application

Comment: i will try this

Comment: Let me know if you face any issues then you can share code link .