# Run tomcat with AppPath

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm currently working on a small software project using tomcat 7. The server runs at the root address (namely localhost:8080/ ). All Servlets are listening on localhost:8080/[ServletPath]. We now want to add an app path between the server name and the ServletPaths such as localhost:8080/[AppPath]/[ServletPath] where [AppPath] is a fixed path such as foo/bar/baz.

Is it possible to set this AppPath in a configuration file and get the Path via ServletContext somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got it, but take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706950/2161180, I think it solves your problem.