# Deploy Spring Boot + WebSocket + Stomp on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I'm having some trouble deploying a Spring Boot + WebSocket + Stomp tutorial available in spring guides for a Tomcat Server

I'm using gradle to create the war where I have the following dependencie

```
"build.gradle"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")

compile("org.webjars:webjars-locator")
compile("org.webjars:sockjs-client:1.0.2")
compile("org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.3")
compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.7")
compile("org.webjars:jquery:3.1.0")

testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Basically i only added the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency and the war and idea plugins.

The code is the one available here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

After the deploy, when I try to access to http://localhost:8080/complete/ i get the following error

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

What can I do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: keep your html and js file in static folder

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure you deploy the WAR with the right context path.
The example code you mentioned assume that you deploy the code to the root path - http://localhost:8080

You can set the context path from your code. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0).

If everything with the context is right you should watch the sever logs for errors that may have blocked the deploy.

Comment: The context is correct because I have done a deploy of another application and works fine. The context is equal to the name of the war file. 

When I watch the logs there are no erros, only the acess log changes. The follow line is added:
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Aug/2017:09:54:58 +0100] "GET /complete/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1012