# Deploy java app to subdirectory

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm building a JAVA (spring) app using Maven to do the install. My pom.xml file contains: `<finalName>tools</finalName>`, so when I install it and upload the war file to tomcat, the domain is `mydomain:8080/tools`. What do I need to change so it uses `mydomain:8080/go/tools` instead?

Comment: `<finalName>go/tools</finalName>`

Comment: I tried that. It created the war file at: target/go/tools.war, but when I upload tools.war to the server, it's still at `:8080/tools`

Comment: Because there is kept also the previous one (`tools`), which you've to delete. have you tried to access `go/tools`?

Comment: define context path in `web.xml` or/and `context.xml` under tomcat/config.

Comment: That was the issue I didn't understand. I couldn't just upload the war file, I had to set the context to /go/tools and tell the server where to pick up the war file instead of uploading it (using the apache tomcat admin gui). Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

> If the Host deployXML flag is set to true, you can install a web
>   application using a Context configuration ".xml" file and an optional
>   ".war" file or web application directory. The Context Path is not used
>   when installing a web application using a context ".xml" configuration
>   file.
>
> A Context configuration ".xml" file can contain valid XML for a web
>   application Context just as if it were configured in your Tomcat
>   server.xml configuration file. Here is an example for Tomcat running
>   on Windows:
>
> Use of the WAR or Directory URL is optional. When used to
>   select a web application ".war" file or directory it overrides any
>   docBase configured in the context configuration ".xml" file.
>
> Here is an example of installing an application using a Context
>   configuration ".xml" file for Tomcat running on Windows.
>
> XML Configuration file URL: file:C:/path/to/context.xml Here is an
>   example of installing an application using a Context configuration
>   ".xml" file and a web application ".war" file located on the server
>   (Tomcat running on Unix).
>
> XML Configuration file URL: file:/path/to/context.xml WAR or Directory
>   URL: jar:file:/path/to/bar.war!/

[Link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/html-manager-howto.html#Deploy_using_a_Context_configuration_%22.xml%22_file)

Or, you can simply change web app context path like this:

> Add a file called `ROOT.xml` in `<catalina_home>/conf/Catalina/localhost/`
>
> This ROOT.xml will override the default settings for the root context
>   of the tomcat installation for that engine and host (Catalina and
>   localhost).
>
> Enter the following to the `ROOT.xml` file;
>
> `<Context    docBase="<yourApp>"    path=""    reloadable="true"  />`

Just set `path` to the path you want e.g. `/go/tools`

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Also, as I mentioned above, you can do it pretty much the same way in either `server.xml` or `context.xml` under `tomcat/config` folder.