# Eclipse/Tomcat : tomcat home page is reachable but app is not

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm currently trying to deploy a simple web app with Eclipse on a tomcat server.

Everything looks fine when i launch the server through Eclipse. `localhost:8080` is working fine and displays the tomcat home page.

However, my app "tutorial-web-spring" is not reachable as `localhost:8080/tutorial-web-spring triggers` a 404.

My app has been well added to my server on the eclipse server tab ...

Btw, I changed my configuration so eclipse use tomcat installation folder and not workspace metadata.

Comment: Are you using xml config or Java config ?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean ,but everything is in xml over here ;)

Comment: Could you please post your properties file? and configs?

Answer (score 0):

**The Context Path**
By default, the context path is `“/”`. If that’s not ideal and you need to change it – to  `tutorial-web-spring`, here’s the quick and simple way to do it via application.properties (spring bot App):

```
server.contextPath=/tutorial-web-spring
```

And for **YAML**-based configuration:

```
server:
    contextPath:/tutorial-web-spring
```

Finally – the change can be done programmatically as well:

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean
  implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.setContextPath("/tutorial-web-spring");
    }
}
```

[SOURCE](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-application-configuration)

Comment: the "/" path sends me directly to the tomcat home page, not to my app

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: Well, none of those solutions seem to work :( same result

Comment: Edit : i changed the Deploy path to mytomcat folder location /webapps and /wtpwebapps (tried both) and still not working..