# Remove Folder Name From Tomcat url

Tags: javascript, java, html, tomcat

I created a webapp and I deployed it on tomcat.

But instead of http://ip:port I need to put http://ip:port/nameOfTheWarFile

to enter. is there a way to remove that name from the url and just use http://ip:port?

Answer (score 2):

Deploy the application as `ROOT.war`.

If you do not want the application name to be inside the URL and to access the application directly on a URL like "http://ip:port", then it means that you want an **empty context path** for your web app.

Based on the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming), you can deploy a web application with the base name equal to `ROOT` (i.e. `ROOT.war` or `ROOT.xml`) to achieve an empty context path:

```
Context Path   | Base File Name | Example File Names 
Empty String   | ROOT           | ROOT.xml, ROOT.war, ROOT
```

Comment: Hi Stefan! Your answer is IMO correct, but I enhanced it slightly to also add some explanation why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the context path of your web application. Another user had a similar question and was answered here.

[How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)