# Tomcat 8, publish 2 .war under same root directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 8 instance which is used to publish multiple web applications.
As today, I have a Spring architecture which produces 2 .war:

- Front-end
- Back-end

And the result is the following:

- http://localhost:8080/my-front-end
- http://localhost:8080/my-back-end

What I would like to achieve is to have a common root path for both these wars. Is this something I can do in Tomcat? In JBOSS or IIS I can use the concept of "Virtual Directory" to achieve that.

My intended result is the following:

- http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-front-end (*my-front-end.war*)
- http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-back-end (*my-back-end.war*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Naming) says to use `#` in the name.

> ```
> Context Name     Base File Name     Example File Names
> /foo             foo                foo.xml, foo.war, foo
> /foo/bar         foo#bar            foo#bar.xml, foo#bar.war, foo#bar
> ```

So use these names for your war files:

`my-app#my-front-end.war`
`my-app#my-back-end.war`

Comment: I choose this one because I asked specifically for Tomcat without using Spring settings

Answer (score 1):

Set the context paths: /my-app/my-front-end and /my-app/my-back-end respectively.

For example, if you are using Spring Boot, then put:

```
server.contextPath=/my-app/my-front-end
```

and

```
server.contextPath=/my-app/my-back-end
```

in **application.properties** file.

If you cannot modify the application's source code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0) you can find out how to configure Tomcat to get the same result.