# tomcat docker-compose cannot access to shared volume

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to deploye a  war on a  tomcat docker container.
Tomcat manager is accessible by default on the listined http port. 
I don't want this behavior. To avoid this i hava done a ROOT.xml context file  as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706950/3143009.

ROOT.xml  is shared via docker volume and  contains context definition :

```
<Context docBase="/usr/tomcat/custom-webapp/app.war" reloadable="true" />
```

To my mind all things are right but  when i try to start  tomcat container, an FileNotFindException occurs telling that /usr/tomcat/custom-webapp/app.war is not  found by tomcat (/usr/tomcat/custom-webapp is also a shared volume containing a app.war file).

my docker-compose file :

```
version : '3'
    tomcat:
        image: tomcat:9.0.27-jdk8-openjdk
        hostname: tomcat
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
        - 10000:8080
        volumes:
        - ./data/logs/:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/
        - ./data/context-ROOT.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
        - ./data/custom-webapp:/usr/local/tomcat/custom-webapp
```

I'm sure that the app.war file is mounted in the container. I can see it when I enter in the container or when i do `docker-compose run tomcat ls /usr/local/tomcat/custom-webapp`. But on startup, tomcat seems to not find the file. That is strange for me.

Has anyone know why tomcat container cannot access to the app.war file ?

below error stacktrace.

```
> tomcat_1    | 25-Oct-2019 14:43:55.287 INFO [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying
> deployment descriptor
> [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] tomcat_1    |
> 25-Oct-2019 14:43:55.307 WARNING [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of
> deployment descriptor
> [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] with an external
> docBase means the directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] in the
> appBase will be ignored tomcat_1    | 25-Oct-2019 14:43:55.331 SEVERE
> [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception
> fixing docBase for context [] tomcat_1    |  
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/tomcat/custom-webapp/mytower.war
> (No such file or directory) tomcat_1    |           at
> java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) tomcat_1    |          
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) tomcat_1   
> |           at
> java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) tomcat_1    |
> at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) tomcat_1   
> |           at
> sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:90)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:615)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:747)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:182)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1831)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) tomcat_1    |
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) tomcat_1    |
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) tomcat_1
> |           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) tomcat_1    |           at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) tomcat_1    |        
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
> tomcat_1    | 25-Oct-2019 14:43:56.054 SEVERE [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error
> deploying deployment descriptor
> [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] tomcat_1    |  
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child tomcat_1    |   
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1831)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) tomcat_1    |
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) tomcat_1    |
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) tomcat_1
> |           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) tomcat_1    |           at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) tomcat_1    |        
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
> tomcat_1    |   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> Failed to start component
> [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2a556333] tomcat_1    |
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4800)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4935)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
> tomcat_1    |           ... 37 more tomcat_1    |   Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified
> [/usr/tomcat/custom-webapp/mytower.war] is not valid tomcat_1    |    
> at
> org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:752)
> tomcat_1    |           at
> org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
> tomcat_1    |           at org.apache
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using volumes but rather [`bind-mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). That means that local host path is mounted into container and content of `./data/custom-webapp` will replace content of `/usr/local/tomcat/custom-webapp` directory.

Therfore your `ROOT.xml` should look like:

```
<Context docBase="/usr/local/tomcat/custom-webapp/app.war" reloadable="true" />
```

and `app.war` should be in `./data/custom-webapp` directory on your host.

Comment: thank you michalk. Actualy the app.war file is in the ./data/custom-webapp directory in my host. And i'm sur it is  mounted in the container. but on tomcat startup the file seems to not be found. 
Could it  be it's because the file is mounted after tomcat startup ?

Comment: @soung Have you changed /usr/tomcat/custom-webapp/app.war to /usr/local/tomcat/custom-webapp/app.war in your XML file and tried it?