# how to add a parameter to spring project before <projectname>/login and after <localhost>:<portnumber> without hardcode?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a Spring MVC project. When I run the application the URL is:

> http://localhost:8080/insureYou/login

but I want:

> http://localhost:8080/contextroot/insureYou/login

Is there any way of doing it without hardcoding?

Comment: Should the extension of */contextroot/* be applied for the whole application or only for the login URL?

Comment: for the whole application

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: What is the current context root of the app? How do you deploy the app? In which server?

Comment: Currently, the context root is "/" meaning http://localhost:8080/insureYou/login where insureYou is project name and login is JSP page. Deploying the project on Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 0):

In a `spring-boot` project you can set the `context-root` by specifying the following property in the `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/yourcontextroot
```

Without spring-boot, it depends on the webserver and Tomcat offers a number of options.
I would personally opt for a `META-INF/context.xml` file in your `war` file containing the necessary information but you can also include the information in the `server.xml` file or in a `ROOT.xml` file.

See the following links for further guidance:

- [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application

This type of deployment however sometimes is handled separately, through an `Apache` server reverse-proxy or through URL rewriting.

I recommend you ascertain whether this type of need is already taken care of by your company's deployment procedures, as you may not need to deal with it at all.