# Error resolving template in a Spring boot Web Application when deployed to external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf, tomcat9

I have a spring boot web application
it is running fine when started from the IDE(I am using Spring Tool Suite)
When I deploy to an external tomcat it is showing errors in all the places.
When I run it from the IDE I use 
http://localhost:8080/login

When I run it from the external tomcat I use
http://localhost:8080/webapp/login

the challenge is that I can't even get the styles populated properly from External Tomcat where as everything is fine when run from the embedded tomcat server.

Error resolving template [folder/page], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Is there something I am missing in the configuration?
In short I can say,
It seems my application is failing when I use the War Name as the application root context
do i have to mention the war name in the controller while returning the views?
if yes, then how? I have tried and it didn't work

Comment: can you add the full error/exception/stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same behavior (`/login` and not `/webapp/login`) for the deployment of the application to your external Tomcat, you should configure the context path.

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1. Name your `.war` file `ROOT.war` and place it in `webapps` directory
2. Follow the different ideas from this question: [How to set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I managed to get it to work by Doing Step 1
The Strange thing is that it works on windows but not on Linux,(Looks like tomcat can't find the deployed and exploded war) working on the fix for windows

Comment: great to hear this, can you mark this answer as correct, so that other developers inthe future benefit from this? Regarding the difference on Linux you might open a new question on StackOverflow