# How can I open my web application in localhost:8080 directly instead of tomcat home page

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat8

How can I open my web application in localhost:8080 instead of the tomcat home page
For example I want mysite.com:8080/mywebapp to open in mysite.com:8080
Without using any reverse proxy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0 should still work

Comment: But if you want to deploy this on the public internet I suggest you use a reverse proxy instead.

Comment: I tried using nginx but it failed the reverse proxy worked but the problem was the css files were not loading at all for example: mysite.com:8080/mywebapp is all good but the same page after reverse proxy (proxy_pass www.mysite.com:8080/mywebapp/) was not loading .min.css files however when I proxy_pass www.mysite.com:8080/ in this case the css files are loading in mysite.com/mywebapp NOTE: mysite is to be replaced by ip address

Comment: You can use Httpd as reverse proxy

Comment: @SOURISHCHANDRAN I have added a solution hope this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this task without any reverse proxy. when you type `http://localhost:8080` your website opens

> Rename the war file to `ROOT.war` and put it tomcat webapps directory and restart tomcat

, Or using Reverse proxy

1. Rename your website to `ROOT.war` in tomcat webapps directory
2. Install `Httpd`
3. Enable Load `mod_proxy_http.so` and `mod_proxy.so` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
4. Add file called example.config under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf`
   And add the following configuration

```
        <VirtualHost *:8080>
          ServerName exmple.com
          ServerAlias *exmple.com
          ServerAdmin user@gmail.com
          ProxyPreserveHost On
          ProxyRequests off
          AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

          <Proxy *>
             Order deny,allow
             Allow from all 
          </Proxy>

          ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/mywebapp  nocanon
          ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/mywebapp 

          LogLevel debug
          ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
          CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggest with httpd but now again I am facing the same problem I faced while using nginx

Comment: What's the issue you got? I mean you didn't able to reach tomcat or what?

Comment: The .min.css files are not loading while using reverse proxy and in console I am getting "failed to load resources: the server responds with status of 404()" for font-awesome.min.css and bootstrap.min.css

Comment: This is strange

Comment: @SOURISHCHANDRAN try this Rename the war file to ROOT.war and put it tomcat webapps directory and restart tomcat

Comment: See for example: the page localhost:8080/mywebapp has a button and all the text are aligned at center where as after reverse proxy localhost/ is loading the page but the button is not there as well as the fonts are not aligned

Comment: I think the reverse proxy works fine because it redirects to the request to the tomcat. So I think it's related to the tomcat configuration. The application website uses incorrect paths or application website security.

Comment: Thanks a lot it did work first I didn't understand what root.war was supposed to do so now I know it did work not the way I wanted but it helped thank you again

Comment: And the actual answer for my question how to open mywebapp in localhost:8080 instead of tomcat was to change the war file name to root

Comment: You are welcome:) , Glad to hear the issue is solved :)