# Run JSF behind reverse proxy with additional subpath

Tags: apache, tomcat, jsf, reverse-proxy

Most already given answers are for situations where you want to hide the app-path. We are in the situation that **only Requests beginning with "http://www.example.com/ourpath" are relayed to our apache**.

Which means our apache rewrites

```
    ProxyPass "/ourpath/MyApp"  "ajp://internalcontainer:8009/MyApp"
    ProxyPassReverse "/ourpath/MyApp"  "ajp://internalcontainer:8009/MyApp"
```

The app itself is now reachable, but jsf builds urls like

```
http://www.example.com/MyApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2
```

And ommits the "ourpath" part. Any idea how we can affect the context-path information of tomcat?

Comment: I don't think that you can. But you could create a rewrite rule on Apache that adds the extra path

Comment: @SimonMartinelli but i need to remove the extra path?`

Comment: No you have to add it in the respone?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli ok but how can a rewrite rule change the uris in the html page?

Comment: Oh sorry. You are right! I simply forgot that it's JSF

Comment: Then the question is: what's the reason for ourpath

Comment: @SimonMartinelli because we create an app for a univention school-server

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got a solution, the internal and external path MUST be the same, otherwise there is no reliable solution.

```
ProxyPass "/ourpath/MyApp"  "ajp://brainyoo2web:8009/ourpath/MyApp"
ProxyPassReverse "/ourpath/MyApp"  "ajp://brainyoo2web:8009/ourpath/MyApp"
```

And ensure the app is deployed in the same path:

```
COPY --from=webbuild /myapp/target/MyApp /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ourpath#MyApp
```

or create a war file with the name ourpath#MyApp.war

The # tells tomcat there is a sub path in the url

Comment: For the 'internal' path, you can, in tomcat at least,  use the context.xml file to explicitly set the path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0